# Check the Hire-Date is Date or Not in talend

Tags: talend

Scenario:

Suppose we have a table with records like this:

```
 EMPNO        HIRE_DATE           
----------   -----------
     1         12-11-87
     2         02-04-88;
     3         02-2323
```

`Empno` is a number and hire_date is in string format. We have to check the hire_date column. If it is in date format like 'dd-mm-yy', then convert it to a date, in the  format  “mm/dd/yy”  and send it to the target. Else, send null.

Output:

```
EMPNO       HIRE_DATE
--------    ---------
   1        11-DEC-87
   2          null
   3          null
```

How can we do this in talend?

Informatica scenario link: https://www.bullraider.com/database/informatica/scenario/88-informatica-scenario29

Comment: Your requirement doesn't fit your output . Explanation is needed beacause a pattern that looks like “mm/dd/yy” doesn't match your output  11-DEC-87

Comment: Hi, I have added the scenario link for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below in expression builder of tmap.

**TalendDate.isDate("12-11-20", "dd-MM-yy",true) ? TalendDate.formatDate("MM/dd/yy",TalendDate.parseDate("dd-MM-yy", "12-11-20" ))  :null**